# Transaction atomicity involving ETH transfers

Tags: solidity, transactions

Consider this imaginary solidity function:

```
function doSomething(){
   msg.sender.transfer(1000);
   a += 1;
   require(false);
}
```

According to the [docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions) variable `a` will not be incremented by 1 because the `require(false)` will cause the transaction to revert. My question is: will the 1000 wei transfer occur or not?

Comment: No, if a transaction is reverted, then it has no effect except to consume the already-used gas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't occur. All the changes will be reverted if the requirement is not fulfilled. In fact, if you try to execute this, for instance, in remix you will get a warning saying that the transaction will fail. If you force the transaction it will be mines but will fail.